# Installing SpaCy English module in Conda

Tags: windows, python-3.x, nlp, anaconda, spacy

While I am able to install spacy in a windows python3 anaconda environment, I cannot get the english module to download

```
   C:\Users\Smith>activate myenvt

   (myenvt) C:\Users\Smith> **python -m spacy download en**

   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in 
   run_module_as_main
   mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)

   File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in 
   _get_module_details
   return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)

   File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in 
   _get_module_details
   __import__(pkg_name)

   File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-
   packages\pip\__init__.py", line 28, in 
   from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa

   File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-
   packages\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in 
   from pip.download import path_to_url

   File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-
   packages\pip\download.py", line 34, in 
   from pip.utils.logging import indent_log

   File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-
   packages\pip\utils\logging.py", line 66, in 
   class ColorizedStreamHandler(logging.StreamHandler):

   File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-
   packages\pip\utils\logging.py", line 72, in ColorizedStreamHandler
   (logging.ERROR, _color_wrap(colorama.Fore.RED)),

   AttributeError: module 'pip._vendor.colorama' has no attribute 'Fore'
```

I tried to overcome this by following the advice here:
[spacy module install in conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383064/spacy-module-install-in-conda)

1) downloading the english module manually from github and
2)  linking to the download

However, when I run this code

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

the second line gives me the following error

```
runfile('C:/Users/Smith/DS/nlp1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Smith/DS')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Smith/DS/nlp1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Smith/DS')

  File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Smith/DS/nlp1.py", line 11, in 
    nlp = spacy.load('en')

  File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 19, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)

  File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 112, in load_model
    return load_model_from_link(name, **overrides)

  File "C:\Users\Smith\Anaconda2\envs\myenvt\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 131, in load_model_from_link
    return cls.load(**overrides)

AttributeError: module 'en' has no attribute 'load'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug which is being addressed: 
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/1792